# Why does this javascript not work in IE but works in other browsers?

Tags: javascript

Yet another reason why I hate IE for being different. I've got this code:

```
var friends = document.getElementById('friendsEmail').value;
...
 var emailArray=new Array();
 emailArray=String(friends).split(','); //error here
```

This works in every other browser. In fact I only added the `Array` declaration and the explicit `String` conversion to get this to work in IE. However, I'm still getting this error

> **Webpage error details**
>
> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1;
>   Trident/4.0; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152;
>   .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 1.1.4322) Timestamp: Wed, 1 Feb
>   2012 22:24:15 UTC
>
> > Message: Object doesn't support this property or method Line: 59 Char:
> >     4 Code: 0

What does IE not like about this? Am I doing something obviously stupid that I'm not seeing?

**EDIT**

This is what I did originally that resulted in IE errors:

```
var emailArray=friends.split(',');
```

This also gives me errors in IE

**EDIT 2**

I'm sorry guys. Turns out that the server was caching an older copy of the .js file and the error line I was looking at was incorrect... I apologize for wasting your time with this. The error turned out to be on a completely different line. For those who are curious it was actually failing because of this line

```
emailArray[count]=emailArray[count].trim();
```

I've already resolved that issue though.

Comment: So perhaps you can remove the "why I hate IE" phrase since it had nothing to to with IE?

Comment: @RobG I could...but it was still IE being different that caused the problem. Just a different function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructors for primitive types are usually not recommended.  You already have a string in your `friends` variable, so just split *that*

Change

```
emailArray = String(friends).split(','); //error here
```

to

```
emailArray = friends.split(','); //should work
```

Comment: I did this originally and this gave me errors as well. I only added in the Array and String to see if that was the issue.

Comment: Object doesn't support this property or method:In IE8 and IE7

Comment: I updated my question. It turns out that this wasn't actually failing. I was looking at the wrong error line.

Answer (score 2):

`split()` creates its own array, so leave out `emailArray=new Array();`

You can just do

```
emailArray = document.getElementById('friendsEmail').value.split(",")
```

Comment: I get the same error without the Array. I added the `Array` declaration after I noticed errors in IE.

Comment: That's true, but has nothing to do with the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

`Split` on IE is not standard. I use this [library](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/cross-browser-split) for cross-browser splitting.

Comment: I did see this library and considered it. I wanted to try fixing the javascript first but I may just use this in the end.

Comment: Steven Levithan's `split()` replacement is good and I'd recommend it, but for this particular case is unnecessary. IE is fine when splitting on a string rather than a regex.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect that the actual issue is that `document.getElementById('friendsEmail').value` is `undefined`. Are you actually trying to get the text content of the element? If so, then this works:

```
var friends = document.getElementById("friendsEmail");
var emailArray = friends.innerText.split(",");
```

Note that a simple test case on a string literal -- like `"str,str1,str2".split(",")` -- would have quickly demonstrated that the `split` was not the issue. It's always best to reduce things to the smallest testable unit. Otherwise, you're just guessing about the source of the error.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JHZJe/

Answer (score 0):

I see no issue with your code.  I think that you may have a problem with the value you are retrieving such that `friends` isn't what you think it is.  You can see in this jsFiddle that the general concept you're using works in IE:

```
var friends = document.getElementById('friendsEmail').value;
var emailArray = friends.split(',');
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/s9S99/.

So, I think the issue is retrieving your value.  That must not be what you think it is (perhaps it is null sometimes).